# lsusb - I get always Couldn't open device. Is this normal?

Tags: usb

When I write `lsusb -v` I always get `"Couldn't open device, some information will be missing"` Is this normal to get for each bus?

P.S: I was trying to read from a laser scanner which is connected via USB. But I was getting "couldn't open serial port". And I wanted to check the port with `lsusb` and I saw that it's written "Couldn't open device" on every one of these usb ports. Even for my mouse it says "Couldn't open" but it's working.

Comment: No, it's definitely not normal. Can you post output of `ls -Al /sys/bus/usb/devices`?

Comment: it was about sudo I guess. Thanks you anyways!

Comment: ok sorry, I didnt't notice you use `-v`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is. You are asking for hardware information so some information might need sudo. See the difference between the 2 ...

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ lsusb -v | grep device
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
```

and when using sudo it disappears though you will get other notices:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ sudo lsusb -v | grep device
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: yes it was about permission. My mistake. Thanks

Comment: this may have helped the poster, but this is not always the answer to the question of "why am I getting 'could not open device - some information may be missing'..." - I run lsusb logged as root via systemd daemon (I can manually reproduce the problem by running `sudo su root` and later `lsusb -vd {myDeviceVidPid}`

Comment: I'm getting the same error message even with `sudo` (or `sudo su`).